# How to apply an attribute to a descendant element? XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

Take a look at the following code:

```xml
<xsl:template match="tocline[@toclevel='2']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::toctitle">
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:attribute name="last">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This template applies the attribute to the tocline element. I want it to apply the attribute to the last toctitle in the nodeset, which can be located at different levels.

With this sample:

```xml
        <tocline id="d1e11" toclevel="1">
            <toctitle>Section 1. Legislative Powers</toctitle>
            <tocline id="d1e40" toclevel="2">
                <toctitle>Separation of Powers and Checks and Balances</toctitle>
                <tocline id="d1e51" toclevel="3">
                    <toctitle>The Theory Elaborated and Implemented</toctitle>
                </tocline>
                <tocline id="d1e189" toclevel="3">
                    <toctitle>Judicial Enforcement</toctitle>
                </tocline>
            </tocline>
        </tocline>
```

I want this:

```xml
        <tocline id="d1e11" toclevel="1">
            <toctitle>Section 1. Legislative Powers</toctitle>
            <tocline id="d1e40" toclevel="2">
                <toctitle>Separation of Powers and Checks and Balances</toctitle>
                <tocline id="d1e51" toclevel="3">
                    <toctitle>The Theory Elaborated and Implemented</toctitle>
                </tocline>
                <tocline id="d1e189" toclevel="3">
                    <toctitle last="true">Judicial Enforcement</toctitle>
                </tocline>
            </tocline>
        </tocline>
```

But I get this:

```xml
        <tocline id="d1e11" toclevel="1">
            <toctitle>Section 1. Legislative Powers</toctitle>
            <tocline id="d1e40" toclevel="2" last="true">
                <toctitle>Separation of Powers and Checks and Balances</toctitle>
                <tocline id="d1e51" toclevel="3">
                    <toctitle>The Theory Elaborated and Implemented</toctitle>
                </tocline>
                <tocline id="d1e189" toclevel="3">
                    <toctitle>Judicial Enforcement</toctitle>
                </tocline>
            </tocline>
        </tocline>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "toctitle
    [. is (ancestor::tocline[@toclevel eq '2'][1]//toctitle)[last()]]">
    <toctitle last="true">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </toctitle>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<tocline id="d1e11" toclevel="1">
    <toctitle>Section 1. Legislative Powers</toctitle>
    <tocline id="d1e40" toclevel="2">
        <toctitle>Separation of Powers and Checks and Balances</toctitle>
        <tocline id="d1e51" toclevel="3">
            <toctitle>The Theory Elaborated and Implemented</toctitle>
        </tocline>
        <tocline id="d1e189" toclevel="3">
            <toctitle>Judicial Enforcement</toctitle>
        </tocline>
    </tocline>
</tocline>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<tocline id="d1e11" toclevel="1">
   <toctitle>Section 1. Legislative Powers</toctitle>
   <tocline id="d1e40" toclevel="2">
      <toctitle>Separation of Powers and Checks and Balances</toctitle>
      <tocline id="d1e51" toclevel="3">
         <toctitle>The Theory Elaborated and Implemented</toctitle>
      </tocline>
      <tocline id="d1e189" toclevel="3">
         <toctitle last="true">Judicial Enforcement</toctitle>
      </tocline>
   </tocline>
</tocline>
```

Comment: This is close. I need the last toctitle element of "each" tocline node with a toclevel="2" attribute. This code provides the last attribute on the very last toctitle element only.

Comment: All toclines have a unique id, which helps this process. So, I need this line, but it needs to be narrowed to one item either by using the id of the tocline or generating one:
toctitle[. is (/*/tocline[@toclevel eq '2']//toctitle[last()])]

Answer (score 0):

I added a key, and here's what I came up with:

```
<xsl:key name="l2id" match="tocline[@toclevel eq '2']" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="toctitle[. is (ancestor-or-self::tocline/key('l2id',@id)/descendant-or-self::toctitle[last()])]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="last">
            <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The response saved me ALOT of time.